# Creating a factor from data across several columns, with priorities, R

Tags: r

I have a dataset similar to this:

```
df<-structure(list(Person = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Stab = c(1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), Shot = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1), Cut = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), ShotBow = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Punched = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0), Slapped = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), `Car Accident` = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Bicycle Accident` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), FellOver = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Person = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Stab = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Shot = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Cut = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), ShotBow = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Punched = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Slapped = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Car Accident` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Bicycle Accident` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), FellOver = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x000002898df11210>, row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

As you can see, the data is about different patients and what happened to them.  Variables in the real dataset are slightly different but kinda like: "stabbed", "shot", "slapped" etc...

I want to squish all these columns into one column that is effectively "how bad is the injury", and working with some of my medical colleagues we've decided on some rankings (again, these aren't the real injuries, I made these ones up).

The rankings for this fake one are:

**Level 1 Severity (worst)**

- Car Accident
- Shot
- ShotBow

**Level 2 Severity (not as bad)**

- Stab
- Cut
- Bicycle Accident

**Level 3 (really not bad)**

- Punched
- Slapped
- Fell Over

What I want to do is create a variable called "Severity" and give patients a 1,2,or 3 based on if they had that respective column (prioritizing the most severe injury). I.e. Patient 1 was stabbed, so they get a "2" (for level 2).  Patient 8 was cut and slapped, so they'd get a 2 for the cut... which would overrule injuries less severe such as the slap. Patient 10 was shot and cut, so they'd get a "1" because shot is more severe than cut.

My expected output would look like this:
[image]

Comment: @akrun just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need a named vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
nm1 <- setNames(c(2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3), names(df)[-1])
df %>%
     mutate(Severity = across(-Person, ~ na_if(., 0) * nm1[[cur_column()]])  %>% 
           {invoke(pmin, c(., na.rm = TRUE))})
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 11
   Person  Stab  Shot   Cut ShotBow Punched Slapped `Car Accident` `Bicycle Accident` FellOver Severity
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl>              <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1      1     1     0     0       0       0       0              0                  0        0        2
 2      2     0     0     1       0       0       0              0                  0        0        2
 3      3     1     1     1       1       1       1              1                  1        1        1
 4      4     0     1     1       0       0       0              0                  0        0        1
 5      5     0     0     0       1       1       0              0                  0        0        1
 6      6     1     0     0       0       0       1              0                  0        0        2
 7      7     0     0     0       0       0       0              0                  1        1        2
 8      8     0     0     1       0       1       0              0                  0        0        2
 9      9     0     0     0       0       0       1              0                  0        1        3
10     10     0     1     1       0       0       0              0                  0        0        1
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you, and I will accept any second.  One thing I wanted to ask is for some clarification on whats going on.  The reason being that when applying to my "real" data where I have differently named columns in different locations (and there's other columns in the dataset not related to injury severity), I'd love to know how to apply this solution.  I.e. if its not too much to ask could you explain each line?

Comment: @JoeCrozier The key part of the solution is constructing the `nm1` If you look at the value and key (which is the column names except the Person), where I created the value corresponding to that of your column name